# Possible causes for SQL Server error "Reason: Unable to determine the initial language and date format."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Today I started seeing SQL connection issues with the following details:

> Description: Login failed for user 'xxxx'. Reason: Unable to determine
>   the initial language and date format.

Doing searches on google, bing, and here did not show any relevant information and I was wondering if anyone knows what could cause this to start happening? (There were a few of these errors but things seem to be running 'properly' since seeing the errors.)

Comment: Open up SSMS and compare that login to some functioning logins.

Comment: And when you find out post an answer so future people have some search result!

Comment: The strange thing is that the login worked fine after seeing the error happen 3 times with-in a minute. (It worked fine before, experienced the error briefly, and now works fine still after). I will gladly post any answer I find out.

Comment: Could be some kind of a AD issue. Is it a windows login or a SQL login?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It is a SQL login though.

Comment: Just updating the I'm still getting these error once in a while and I still haven't figured out the cause